# Java/JavaFX8: Perform action when input in TextField has certain length

Tags: java, action, javafx-8, string-length, controlsfx

I am currently using the AutoComplete TextField functionality from ControlsFX to show suggestions when the user is typing. The amount of suggestions is large, and therefore the list doesn't fit on the page.

I would like to set the length of the list of strings to a maximum, but this is not yet possible in ControlsFX (as fas as I can conclude that). Therefore, I was thinking of a workaround, in which the list only shows up when the user has typed a string of 3 characters or more.

I have now set this action to execute when the TextField is clicked (where searchCustomer is my TextField):

```
@FXML
private void searchCustomer() {
    //Get all customers from shop
    String[][] customersOfShop = octocash.Main.databaseConnection.getData("some query", 
                    Arrays.asList("some columname"));

    //Convert 2D array to 1D array
    int noOfRows = customersOfShop.length;
    String[] customersForList = new String[noOfRows];
    for(int k=0; k<noOfRows; k++) {
        customersForList[k] = customersOfShop[k][0];
    }
    //Set values to AutoComplete TextField
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchCustomer, customersForList);
}
```

How to do this in java/javaFX8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of approaches can be to observe text length:

```
IntegerBinding ib = Bindings.length(textField.textProperty());

ib.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
    if(newValue.intValue() >= 3) {
        // trigger auto complete
    }
});
```